# GeoFence crash on API 33

Tags: android, kotlin, android-geofence

I'm currently working on a GeoFence app and whenever I try to create a radius it crash. This only happens on API 33, I've emulated this app on API 30 and it works. LogCat says something about a PendingIntent FLAG. If anyone knows how to solve this I will be very thankful. Here's the main code
https://gist.github.com/LuchoD03/0f30c390d11225a80cae489c00255043

[LogCat Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFtyH.png)

Comment: First, do not post images or links to codes and errors.  Post them as text here.  Secondly, the crash says exactly what the problem is.  The pending intent needs one of two flags on API 33 and up.  Add one.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to FLAG_MUTABLE .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).